# Имеет ли смысл мой (апплет?) для окон?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!
Недавно написал небольшой (я правда не знаю, как это классифицировать) на js.

Его суть в том, что он исользует маленькую библиотеку для подгрузки jQuery, jQueryTouch и jQueryUI, а так же для работы с DOM по основным нуждам, в общем, это не самое главное.

Далее, используя более оптимизированный ajax jQuery, drar'n'drop и resizable, создаются окна внутри сайта, все параметры которых указаны в файлах в виде объектов, в окна эти грузится контент их html файла, подключается js, css и т.д. (короче говоря, это что-то типа миниатюрного сайта).

Код окон, в свою очередь, остаётся в памяти, чтоб при повторном открытии не грузить всё заново.

Работает это всё, кстати, очень удобно- нужно просто выполнить функцию, передав ей название конфиг-файла, чтоб открыть окно;

И теперь возникает резонный вопрос: "А имеет ли это всё какую-то пользу?"...

---

*Более подробно*

---

есть структура

```
wins/
    winEngine.js
    jQuery.js
    jQueryTouch
    jQueryUI.js
    css.css
    prog/
        win1.jprog
        bin/
            win1/
                style.css
                html.html
                js.js
```

---

к странице подкоючается wins/winEngine.js, в котором выполняется проверка на нужные библиотеки, после чего соответствующие подключаются.
для подключения этих самых "окон" выполняется функция createWin('win1','body');

После чего из bin/"папка"/ подключается всё, что указано в .jprog файле и создаётся окно в "body"(если всё было раннее загружено, то повторная загрузка не происходит);

Сейчас это дело выглядит как-то так(мне было просто лень делать нормальный дизайн, на скрине- просто консолька, открытая в двух окнах):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

это код .jprog файла

```
{
    name:"super proga",
    version:"1.2.3",
    content:"html.html",
    func:function(){},
    winMax:2,
    processor:true,
    binFolder:"win1",
    css:["stl.css"],
    js:["cmd.js"],
    window:true,
    selector:"this"
}
```

html.html

```
<input type='text' id='gg'>
<br>
<div id='dd'>
    ggvp
</div>
<br>
<div id='ggtext'>
    </div>
<button onmousedown='ggvp($this".querySelector("#gg"))'>
    enter
</button>
```

cmd.js

```
var ggvp= function(el){eval(el.val());el.val("");};
```

stl.css

```
$this #dd{background:yellow;}
```

Comment: Может хотя бы скриншот или ссылку на демо приложите, а то как-то непонятно о чем речь идет.

Comment: Ну, если для вас "Работает это всё, кстати, очень удобно", то это точно имеет хоть какую-то пользу, в остальном не ясно в чем суть.

Comment: Это Single Page Application

Comment: Значительно дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Михаил если ваша задача сделать имитацию OS на web-странице, то явно имеет смысл. Хотя для таких целей уже давно изобрели SPA и фреймворки вроде angular, react.js, vue.js. На них имитацию OS можно будет сделать в разы быстрее

Comment: Самое главное- систематизация и оптимизация.. Дело в том, что я уже имею опыт создания подобного... Я пытался создать соц сеть с окнами, но потерпел фиаско, когда посмотрел на код, который писался и костылился пол года.. И ещё там всё страшно лагало